# Can we use UART COMMUNICATION with MCP23017?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, uart, serial-data

I am using MCP23017 as a GPIO expander with Arduino in my project. I have too many serial devices and no pins left on Arduino for UART communication.

I am wondering if I can use this MCP23017 GPIO expander pins for UART communication or not?

Comment: with SoftwareSerial? no

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one way.

In theory you could use the GPIO pins of the mcp23017 to control a couple of 2-way multiplexers. With these multiplexers you could split your Rx/Tx pins to more than one serial bus.

May it be obvious that you cannot used the split busses at the same time. So depending on your specific use-case this may or may not be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No. No you can't. Serial takes precise timing and fast reactions. Things you can't do with a remote device like that.

Instead there are SPI UART devices specifically for the job, such as the MAX3107.